# ArcGIS collector and related table

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-online, arcgis-collector

I am having a problem with related table in collector for ArcGIS. I have a feature class with a related table defined by a relationship class of type simple, 1:1 cardinality, and forward notification. I have also activated the pop-up for both the feature class and the table in ArcGIS online. When I enter data in Collector in feature class, the related table appears and I can enter data into it too. After pressing "Done", when I try to access the related table data tapping "view", I get an error saying that the data could not be found. When I access the related table in ArcGIS online, I can see that the data I entered are stored in the table but as soon as I try to access it with pop-up, I get the same error. Can anyone tell me, what I am missing here or what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What version are you working with? Looks like starting at 10.3, you can indeed access related tables: http://doc.arcgis.com/en/collector/android/create-maps/faqs-create-map.htm#anchor8

Comment: I'm working with 10.3...As I mentioned, I can access related table. My only problem is that it shows data couldn't be found after I populate the related table with new data. May be it's due to some issues with relationship class.

Comment: Create field type long in related table. It is a foreign key to feature objectID. Works for me with 1:M (argis 10.2) relationship class. Funny enough when you'll download feature service back to desktop, you'll find key replaced by globalId and rel_globalid

Answer (score 1):

ObjectID based relationships are not supported in Collector. There is a risk of using OID based relationships and offline where a value could be duplicated and break the relationship. I would recommend using GlobalID(PK) to GUID (FK) field (Not GlobalID to GlobalID). You can also use fields like a string or integer field but there is a risk of getting duplicate field values which could introduce errors in your data set.